# Why Sql server 2014 run very slow when checking with dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

When am executing below query, it takes almost 2.30 min.

```
select Clientid,
       Sum(Qty * Rate) BuyVolume 
from   Table1 S(nolock) 
  join table2 T on T.ReferrentClientId = S.Clientid 
where  S.Column2 = 'B' 
and    S.Date >= T.Date  
and    S.Date <= T.Date  +30
Group by Clientid
```

but when i give T.Date as '2016-12-23 00:00:00.000', the result is getting in 1 sec.

```
select Clientid,
       Sum(Qty * Rate) BuyVolume 
from   Table1 S(nolock) 
  join table2 T on T.ReferrentClientId = S.Clientid 
where  S.Column2= 'B' 
and    S.Date >= '2015-12-23 00:00:00.000'
and    S.Date <= '2016-01-22 00:00:00.000' 
Group by Clientid
```

The table1 contains 47589000 rows and table2  only contain 5 rows.
The result set only contains two rows. Both date columns is in Datetime format.

Is there any way to speed up my execution.

Comment: Can you post execution plans, and details of any indexes?

Comment: I'm sure you have your reasons for using the no lock table hint, but [this article](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) makes some arguments against its use.  TL/DR; NoLock can return results that do not match the underlying data.

Comment: Does it help if you move the date comparisons from `WHERE` to `ON` clause?

Comment: @Salman A it didn't helped me...

Comment: How curious. I wouldn't expect a 5 row table to make any difference to anything. Please post the two execution plans (CTRL-L)

Comment: I would suggest creating multiple indexes on table1. Try all combinations of columns involved e.g. `(Column2, Date) INCLUDE (ClientID, Qty, Rate)`, `(Date, Column2) INCLUDE (ClientID, Qty, Rate)`, `(Date, Column2, ClientID) INCLUDE (Qty, Rate)`. Then drop those that are not used.

Comment: In the margin: Aaron Bertrand wrote a brilliant article on handling date ranges: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries

Comment: What are the indexes on `Table1`. This is just a hunch, but it's possible that the second query can do almost all of it's work from an index on `Table1` whereas the first one can't... Show the indexes!

Comment: What are the data types of the two `Date` columns?

Comment: Both are Datetime

Comment: and if you change `t.date+30` to `DATEADD(dd, 30, t.date)`?  not that I'm expecting much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is definitely in how the query is being optimized.  You should look at the execution plans to get more information.

This is your query:

```
select Clientid, Sum(Qty*Rate) as BuyVolume
from Table1 S join
     table2 T
     on T.ReferrentClientId = S.Clientid
where S.Column2 = 'B' and
      S.Date >= T.Date and 
      S.Date <=  T.Date + 30
Group by Clientid;
```

The first suggestion is an index on `Table1(Column2, Date, ClientId)`.

However, because `table2` is so small, you really want to make that the driving table for the `join`.  That would suggest an alternative index on `Table1(ClientId, Column2, Date)`.  This should do the `join` first, which should significantly reduce the number of rows being processed.

Comment: There is already index in Table1 with the field (Column2, Date, ClientId). And i changed the join order. but no result..!!

Comment: If the date field has high cardinality, and the ClientID has low cardinality, wouldn't the first index be limitted in its usefulness, regardless of table size?

Comment: @bino: this answer is suggesting to Not use the index you have, but rather index the columns in a different order (with date being last, most importantly)

Comment: @Bino Changing the join order will not have effect in itself, as the engine is free to rearrange if it thinks it is better to do so. If you want to force a join order, use the `FORCE ORDER` query hint (cf [Query Hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx)). Note that these sort of hints should be used **as a last resort** only (i.e. if all else fails).

Comment: @TT. . . . You seem confused about something.  MatBailie's comment is about the order of keys in the index, not `join` order.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I took his statement *"And i changed the join order."* literally... accidents happen, right ;-)

Answer (score 0):

My hunch as to what is going on here is that in the first query the `WHERE` clause requires looking up the `Date` value for each record in the join, whereas in the second query this does not need to happen.  One possibility is that the query optimizer is completely skipping the step of looking up values in `table2` during execution of the `WHERE` clause in your second query.

Note that the `WHERE` clause executes before `GROUP BY`, so these queries appear to be identical other than the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Anonymous downvotes are rude, and benefit no one.  Please leave feedback, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
select Clientid,
       Sum(Qty * Rate) BuyVolume 
from   Table1 S(nolock) 
  join table2 T on T.ReferrentClientId = S.Clientid 
where  S.Column2 = 'B' 
and    S.Date between T.Date and T.Date + 30
and    S.Date between (select min(Date) from table2) and (select max(Date) from table2) + 30
Group by Clientid
```

Answer (score 0):

as per the different suggestions from here i created a `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` on my table as below.

```
create NONCLUSTERED  index myIndex 
on Table1(Column2) include (Date,Clientid,qty,rate)
```

Now it only taking 7 sec for getting the result. Thanks for all the answers and comments.